# Xamarin Could not find schema information for the element

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have been following the steps in this xamarin link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/animation/frame_animation and whenever I open that xml file I keep on getting 7 messages stating that it could not find schema information for the element 'item'.
The weird thing is that the application starts when I close that xml and the animation works fine but having a message in one of my project just disturbs me.
I have tried cleaning and rebuilding yet nothing changed.